# Serial.print in arduino not write variables

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm developing in arduino but I'm having problem to write in Serial

My code:

```
void send(String prefix, String cmd, String param) {
    Serial.print("@");
    Serial.print(prefix);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(cmd);
    if (param.length() > 0) {
        Serial.print("=");
        Serial.print(param);
    }
    Serial.print(";");
}

void sendComand(String cmd, String param)
{
    send("CMD", "xxx", "param");
}
```

Result:

```
@:;@:;@:;@:;@:;@:;@:;@:;@:;@:;
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: What code are you actually executing? These are just definitions

Comment: Are you sure that `sendCommand` is the only method that is calling `send()`?

Comment: your `sendComand` actually doesn't use any of the parameters. You call send with the hardcoded strings "CMD" and "param" not the values of the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I commented ***cmd.reserve(64);*** and everythings worked. I putted this code to try to optimize, but it not worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Serial.print function does support printing variables of type String, so your code should work.  The fact that it is printing nothing when you try and print a variable implies you are not printing what you think you are.
Are you sure you are calling the send function that you think you are calling, is there only one (including in any libraries you have loaded).
Print the length of each of the parameters you pass to send, I suspect that they are all zero or it will crash because they are null.

If this doesn't help then I suggest that you have this post moved to the Arduino SO and post a minimal complete example.

Answer (score -2):

Doing anothers tests, I believe that the problem is in another part of my code, but affect another parts. In the *loop* method I implemented a *"watch dog"* code, to warn to software that the hardware is alive. But when I put a new value in watchDogTimeHardware variable, look like that memory has been corrupted.

```
unsigned long watchDogTimeHardware = 0L;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  cmd.reserve(64);
}

void loop()
{

  if (millis() > watchDogTimeHardware) {
    watchDogTimeHardware = millis() + 1000L; // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    sendComand(OUT_WATCH_DOG, "");
  }
}
```

I dont know whats happening

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer to your question, but rather some extension of the question

Comment: No its a separate question

Comment: I posted this answer because the original problem is affected by another part of my code.

Comment: If that is true then it suggests you are overflowing a variable somewhere, but since you haven't posted your full code no one can check.